# Name of the book/album with an entire road/boulevard photographed

Tags: film, books, photobooks

I remember about a photography documentary seen some time ago. The photographer published a book containing an entire road/boulevard. I can't remember the name of the artist. Do you know about such a work?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could recall the location\country of this documentary along with the period in which it was made. Also, you could try checking out the Amazon documentary photography section sorting it by publication time.

Comment: I think the pictures were made in U.S. and the documentary was made in the last 10 years(I know... 10 years mean a lot). It was a documentary about the history of photography. I have seen it on Viasat History a year ago.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The book is called [Twentysix Gasoline Stations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twentysix_Gasoline_Stations) and it was done by Ed Ruscha. It contains 2,5 miles from a Sunset Boulevard area called The Strip. This was done with a automatic camera mounted on a truck. All these were shown in the documentary called "[The Genius of Photography](http://www.bbc.co.uk/photography/genius/gallery/)".

Comment: Seitaridis, have you considered awarding the bounty to mattdm's answer ? http://photo.stackexchange.com/privileges/set-bounties

Comment: I have answered my own question.

Comment: ops, you're right :-) sorry for the confusion, I misread the icon. Then in any case you can award the bounty to yourself. At least you will get the Benefactor badge :-)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it was [Biscayne Boulevard "A Moment in Time"](http://www.blurb.com/books/551903) by [Andrew Kaufman](http://www.andrewkaufman.net).

Comment: The photographer was about 60-70 years in the documentary and  each page of the album was a part of the boulevard filmed/photographed continuously, similar to Google Street view. Don't know the exact distance, but there were several kilometers.